# To do a backup x to make a backup

Tags: verbs, do-vs-make

I know we usually use backup as a verb, but if I wanted to use do/make, which one would be correct? I researched on google and found both usages, so I'm not sure which one is right

Comment: Since a backup is supposed to be a thing you are creating, use make.

Comment: I would also consider "running a backup", because backup is not only a word for the saved data, but also for the process. One certainly says "Please don't power the machine off, the backup is still running."

Comment: I would *do* or *run* a "backup", but *make* a "backup copy" or "backup tape" or "backup file".

Comment: Though it is not the ultimate aim of your question, I feel I should comment that "backup" is never (supposed to be) a verb. It should be written as "back up" in that case, as in "Back up that hard drive!" See [the Wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backup)'s first line.

Comment: *"Please, do back up and park your car by the corner!"* (Though I take it you mean the computer data kind of backup.)

Answer (score 1):

According to [Google Ngram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=do+a+backup%2Cmake+a+backup%2Cperform+a+backup%2Crun+a+backup&year_start=190&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=), “make a backup” is by far the most common, but that's in part because it's often used in larger phrases such as “make a backup copy”. “Perform a backup” is less common but also possible. “Do a backup” and “run a backup” are even less common.

This meshes well with my personal experience: I'd normally use “make a backup” in casual speech or writing, or “perform a backup” to be more precise. I wouldn't *do* or *run* a backup.

Comment: I always say "take a backup".  Not sure where I am taking it but it's definitely the one I use most.